# Migration for Users Following Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, I have models for Users and Projects.

I want users to have the ability to follow many projects. So users has_many projects, and projects belongs_to users that not only created them but users that follow them too.

So I generated a migration called `ProjectRelationship` and tried to make it flow below, but it doesn't seem to work. Can somebody help me fix my associations?

Thanks for the help!

**project_relationship.rb**

```
class ProjectRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

**project.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :project_relationships
has_many :followers, through: :project_relationships, source: :user
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :projects
has_many :project_relationships
has_many :projects_followed, through: :project_relationships, source: :project
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "project_relationships", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "follower_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",     :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",     :null => false
  t.integer  "projectuser_id"
end

add_index "project_relationships", ["follower_id"], :name => "index_project_relationships_on_follower_id", :unique => true
add_index "project_relationships", ["projectuser_id"], :name => "index_project_relationships_on_projectuser_id"
```

**projects/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @project.followers.count %>
```

Comment: So, what is the actual question? What is happening when you run the code and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: i'm not sure if i got the associations correct as i get the following error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Projects#show; SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: project_relationships.project_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_relationships" ON "users"."id" = "project_relationships"."user_id" WHERE "project_relationships"."project_id" = 23

Comment: Did you actually create migrations for the all of the models? Your schema looks like all you created was a migration for the project_relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the foreign keys. The ProjectRelationship model will be expecting the corresponding table to have a "user_id" and "project_id" columns. However, you used different names. So either specify the foreign keys:

```
class ProjectRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "follower_id"
  belongs_to :project, foreign_key: "projectuser_id"
end
```

or change the column names in your migration:

```
create_table :project_relationships do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :project_id
  ...
end
```

You will also need to specify the foreign key in your other models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :project_relationships, foreign_key: "projectuser_id"
  has_many :followers, through: :project_relationships, source: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :project_relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id"
  has_many :projects_followed, through: :project_relationships, source: :project
end
```

Comment: ok, will go with the specify foreign keys method. so if i do that, i would specify foreign keys in all models right? projectrelationship, project, and user. i will test this tonight

Comment: Yes, you have to specify them where Rails can't deduce them from the name of the model. If Rails sees `belongs_to :user` it will expect a foreign key of `"user_id"`, so you need to tell it you used a different one. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for all your help. please see my updated question below, i will check your response right after.

Comment: No problem. Try adding `attr_accessible :follower_id` to your User model, which will allow you to set it by mass assignment. However, I don't understand why are you doing `current_user.project_relationships.build(follower_id: @project.id)`, maybe you meant `current_user.project_relationships.build(projectuser_id: @project.id)`? Because in that case you will need to add `attr_accessible :projectuser_id` to your Project model instead.

Comment: Thanks. I added 'attr_accessible :projectuser_id' to my 'projectrelationship model' as that seemed to rid the error. I also updated the _follow and _unfollow buttons. Pages load with no error, but doesn't seem to actually update with a follow and change to the unfollow button for example. Do you know why?

Comment: Does it have to do with the items I put in user.rb?

Comment: The form will work through ajax but if you also want the button to change you will need to do that manually (using jQuery, for example). The same with the followers count. But let's try to isolate the problem, does the ProjectRelationship get created and saved to the database when you click the Follow button?

Comment: Right now it doesn't get saved to database when I click Follow button. But the URL shows "?utf8=✓&authenticity_token=5EQmU0EkHB5yKDYakqL78piMWzZl0CfdpHFEqBeQiN4%3D&project_relationship%5Bprojectuser_id%5D=23&commit=Follow+Project" after the main URL after I click follow.

Comment: Also, I have been trying to follow Michael Hartl's chapter 11 tutorial online, and I don't need to use AJAX as long as I am letting page refresh after clicking. Thus, my _follow_form.html.erb has the if current_user is following project, to render follow or unfollow button. Do you know how to fix or should I repost this question and close out this question? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

@roma149 - Thanks for your response. I updated the controllers, routes, and what you said. No errors generate, but when I click the button follow in _follow.html.erb, it does not seem to follow the project or update the count "@project.followers.count"

Moved details to here: [Why doesn't my user follow/unfollow button work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136997/ruby-on-rails-user-follow-unfollow-button)