# Why doesn't my user follow/unfollow button work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on building an application (following [Michael Hartl's chapter 11](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top)) where users can follow projects that are created by other users.

I created a ProjectRelationship model to hold two components: follower_id for the users and projectuser_id for the projects. The foreign keys have been set up as such.

Right now, my `_follow_form.html.erb` page renders "follow" or "unfollow" depending on whether the `current_user` is following the project. Please see my code below and see what I am missing.

Right now, the follow button is generated on each project show page. But when I click the button follow button that is generated by `_follow.html.erb`, it does not seem to follow the project or update the count when I call `@project.followers.count` as the POST is not happening.

And thus, when I click follow button, the URL becomes all jumbled. See example:

```
#Goes from
domain.com/projects/21

#to
domain.com/projects/21?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=5EQmU0EkHB5yKDYakqL78piMWzZl0CfdpHFEqBeQiN4%3D&project_relationship%5Bprojectuser_id%5D=21&commit=Follow%22
```

****Update: 
    It seems to work now, but I'm not sure if I really changed anything but got rid of the follower_id index :unique => true through a migration change.**

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "project_relationships", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "follower_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",     :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",     :null => false
  t.integer  "projectuser_id"
end

add_index "project_relationships", ["follower_id"], :name => "index_project_relationships_on_follower_id", :unique => true
add_index "project_relationships", ["projectuser_id"], :name => "index_project_relationships_on_projectuser_id"
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :projects do       
  resources :comments 
  member do
    get :following
  end   
end
resources :project_relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

**project_relationship.rb**

```
class ProjectRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :projectuser_id

   belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "follower_id"
   belongs_to :project, foreign_key: "projectuser_id"
end
```

**project.rb**

```
has_many :project_relationships, foreign_key: "projectuser_id"
has_many :favorited_by, through: :project_relationships, source: :user
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :project_relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id"
has_many :followed_projects, through: :project_relationships, source: :project

def following_project?(project)
  project_relationships.find_by_follower_id(project.id)
end

def follow_project!(project)
  project_relationships.create!(projectuser_id: project.id)
end

def project_unfollow!(project)
  project_relationships.find_by_projectuser_id(project.id).destroy
end
```

**project_relationships_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectRelationshipsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_relationship][:projectuser_id])
    current_user.follow_project!(@project)
    redirect_to @project
  end

  def destroy
    @project = ProjectRelationship.find(params[:id]).followed_project
    current_user.project_unfollow!(@project)
    redirect_to @project
  end
end
```

**projects/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
```

**projects/_follow_form.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.following_project?(@project) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
<% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
<% end %>
```

**projects/_follow.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.project_relationships.build(projectuser_id: @project.id)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :projectuser_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**projects/_unfollow.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.project_relationships.find_by_projectuser_id(@project),
         html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: is your follow and unfollow query create or destroy successfully? or just can't get the count of the according project only?

Comment: The create/destroy does not work I believe because when I click "follow" button, nothing is created in the database for projectrelationship.

Comment: I saw that your follow form is using js? remote: true, do you mind to post your js as well?

Comment: erm, yea..or you dont do any js for your form submission??

Comment: erm, I saw the tutorial is quite complete, try to alert("Testing"); in your create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb ,to see whether your js is working right.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I updated the follow/unfollow html.erb files so that it is not running js, but similar to code here: (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#code-follow_form). Still not working though.

Comment: erm, try puts your value in your form and see whether all your value is captured in the form. see your rails server log and see what is happening, is that correctly Post and delete

Comment: I tried running tail -f log/development.log and not sure what I am looking for? Sorry, am new to this.

Comment: hmm, you can do in your ProjectRelationshipsController, puts params[:project_relationship][:projectuser_id], and see if there is correct value passing into and successfully post. (when you start the server, rails server, thats is your log,you can check from there)

Comment: Ok, doesn't seem to be posting.

Comment: When I try to follow, my URL of the project gets all funky from "http://localhost:3000/projects/21" to "http://localhost:3000/projects/21?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=5EQmU0EkHB5yKDYakqL78piMWzZl0CfdpHFEqBeQiN4%3D&project_relationship%5Bprojectuser_id%5D=21&commit=Follow"

Comment: You could try to debug your issue by raising the incoming params in a controller action with `raise params.inspect` or `raise params.to_yaml`. Which form is "render 'show_follow'" rendering?

Comment: I miswrote as it is the _follow_form.html.erb that renders the follow/unfollow. I raised prams.to_yaml and see: --- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
utf8: ✓ 
authenticity_token: Ubt8T2qd5N+nbDFMKPp5A4RaLyWwFhArcAIfBPUsOSA= 
project_relationship: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my follow/unfollow form was embedded in another form which caused the error. Once taken out, worked!

Answer (score 0):

First of all - if you run `projectfollow!(project)` and `projectunfollow!(project)` in your console (with a user, project etc) do they work properly?

For your forms try the following instead and see if it works:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.project_relationships.build, url: project_relationships_path(project_id: @project.id)) do |f| %>
```

Then in your project relationships controller:

```
class ProjectRelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    current_user.projectfollow!(@project)
    redirect_to @project
  end
end
```

So if your create URL is `/project_relationships` (via POST), the above should post to `/project_relationships?project_id=5` and then the controller can find that project.

Also, try to rename your methods so they make sense:

```
def following_project?(project)
end

def follow_project!(project)
end

def unfollow_project!(project)
end
```

Now `current_user.following_project?(project)` makes a lot of sense!

#### Update

Ok, I think the following is the problem, in your `create` action you're getting the id from the params:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_relationship][:projectuser_id])
```

However in your form you're not setting the value of the hidden field:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :projectuser_id %>
```

Change it to the following and see if it works:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :projectuser_id, value: @project.id %> # or wherever the id is from
```

Comment: I renamed my following/follow/unfollow methods as you suggested. I ran these methods in my console and it worked properly updating my database. I then updated the form for _follow.html.erb, the projectrelationships controller (see response below), but still does not work.

Comment: Postings are not being made when the "follow" button is clicked.

Comment: Per update, did not fix. I am not sure if that is the issue because if I change f.hidden_field to f.text_field, it creates a text field that populates with the :project.id already since I called upon it in the build link before it.